# Domain class iteration in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, iteration

I have the following relationship between two domain classes:

```
class Emp {
  String name
  hasMany = [itemsell:Item, itembuy:Item]
}

class Item {
   String name
}
```

And I need to know what items are common to both collections for a given Emp (itemsell and itembuy); how can I do such iteration?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make these changes to the Emp class

```
class Emp {
  String name
  hasMany = [itemsell:Item, itembuy:Item]

  // Modifications
  Collection<Item> getCommonItems() {
      itemsell.intersect(itembuy)
  }    

  static transients = [ 'commonItems' ]
}
```

You can then call `emp.commonItems` to get the items in common. You should add `commonItems` to the `transients` list, so that GORM understands that this is not a persistent property

Comment: Didn't know about intersect.. Love it!

Answer (score 1):

Use the findAll method on one of the collections. Something like this:

```
def similarItems(itemsell, itembuy) {
   itemsell.findAll{ sell -> itembuy.contains(sell) }
}
```